# Does John James support Trump walking away from corona relief negotiations?

Tags: united-states, senate, covid-19

I was reading about a US senate candidate for Michigan named [John E, James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_E._James).

[A campaign website paid for by the Michigan Democratic State Central Committee](https://www.johnjamesrevealed.com/john-james-revealed-does-john-james-support-trump-walking-away-from-covid-relief-negotiations/) makes the claim that he supports Trump abandoning negotiations for stimulus. Is there reasonable reason to believe that that is true?

Answer (score 2):

This is a campaign website accusing James of supporting Trump's and McConnell's position on the basis that James has refused to make any comment on it. The accusation isn't unreasonable — Trump has endorsed James, and James is on record as wholeheartedly supporting Trump — but drawing inferences from non-statements is always questionable. File this in the credible but unproven drawer, I suppose...